# Spark read from in-memory GCS created using LocalStorageHelper

Tags: scala, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, integration-testing

I am trying to write integration test for my spark ingestion application which ingests data to GCS. For this I am creating an in-memory GCS using [LocalStorageHelper](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/blob/master/TESTING.md#testing-code-that-uses-storage). But when spark tries to read file from this storage I get following error.

> java.io.IOException: Error getting access token from metadata server
>   at:
>   http://169.254.169.254/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token

Below is my code

```
val testBucketName = "test-bucket"
val gcsIngestionLocation = s"gs://${testBucketName}/test/path/fake.txt"
prepareTestGcs(testBucketName)
createDataFrame(gcsIngestionLocation)

private def prepareTestGcs(testBucketName: String) = {
  import com.google.cloud.storage.contrib.nio.testing.LocalStorageHelper
  import com.google.cloud.storage.BlobId
  import com.google.cloud.storage.BlobInfo
  import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
  val storage = LocalStorageHelper.getOptions.getService
  val blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(BlobId.of(testBucketName, "test/path/fake.txt")).build
  storage.create(blobInfo, "randomContent".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
}

private def createDataFrame(dataPath: String) =
spark.read
.option("header", true)
.csv(dataPath)
```

Comment: Where are you running this code? The metadata server is only available in GCP within a compute instance (Dataproc, Compute Engine, etc.).

Comment: I am running it locally. Since it is integration test and has to run on my CI server, I cannot run it on Dataproc/ Compute Engine. Also my thinking is, since it is in-memory mocked up instance, it should run anywhere.

Comment: If you are accessing a GCP only resource then you will either need to have a case condition or mock the metadata server. Your code is trying to access the Compute Engine Default Service Account which only exists in GCP. You can solve this by modifying your code to use a service account JSON key file that you specify.

Comment: I am not sure what you created. You do not create a Compute Engine default service account. You can create a service account, assign the desired IAM roles and then download the JSON key file. Please try to be exact in what you say, don't assume as this will make a difference in my comments. Once you download the key file you need to specify that in your code. I don't write GCP code in Scala/Java so you will need to look up the library interface for "Application Default Credentials".